# How to return control back to terminal in C using termios

Tags: c, linux, termios

I am creating a shell which will mimic the behavior of the shell in Linux, like executing commands such as **ls, mkdir, find** etc, Now i have used **termios** to listen for arrow key press and **Enter** key press, if the user presses the up arrow key then show the user the previously executed command. But after executing my shell program, after entering first command like for instance: `ls` the output of the command will be displayed but after that i am unable to execute another command as typing in terminal and pressing Enter just print the text back on new line and doesn't execute it.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
static int peek_character = -1;
void init_keyboard();
void close_keyboard();
int kbhit();
int readch();


int main() {

    int ch;
    char str[1000][200];
    init_keyboard();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(ch != 'q') {

    if(kbhit()) {

        ch = readch();

        if (ch == 10) {
            system(str[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            str[i][j] = ch;

            j++;
        }

    }

}
    close_keyboard();
    exit(0);
}

void init_keyboard() {
    tcgetattr(0, &initial_settings);
    new_settings = initial_settings;
    // new_settings.c_iflag &= ~BRKINT;
    // new_settings.c_iflag &= ICRNL;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ECHO;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);

}

void close_keyboard() {

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);

}

int kbhit() {
    char ch;
    int nread;

    if (peek_character != -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    nread = read(0, &ch,1);
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);

    if (nread == 1) {
        peek_character = ch;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int readch() {
    char ch;

    if (peek_character != -1) {
        ch = peek_character;
        peek_character = -1;
        return ch;
    }

    read(0, &ch,1);
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `read(0, &ch,5);` in readch(), when `ch` is only sized to take one char?

Comment: my bad it should be `1` not `5`

Comment: I am not seeing code to look for an arrow key  (which actually can differ a lot between various terminal protocols).  Do you think you were doing that yet?

Comment: You might consider looking at the `ncurses` library, which is designed to assist on arrow-key and scrolling type programs

Comment: i haven't implemented the arrow key functionality yet i just need to know how i can get back the control of the terminal. i am not allowed to use ncurses

Comment: Well, a limited form of redrawing a line is to send a return code, to bring you to the start of a line, followed by enough space characters to erase the old contents.  Then another return and follow that by the characters you want shown on the line (i.e. the old command).  Is that 'control' enough?

Answer (score 0):

you need fork() to create new process cause system() execute your commande and get out ...
try this code :

```
int main() {

int ch;
char str[1000][200];
init_keyboard();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
pid_t father;
father = 0;

while(ch != 'q') {

if(kbhit()) {

    ch = readch();

    father = fork();
    if (father == 0)
    {
        if (ch == 10) {
          system(str[i]);
          i++;
        } else {
        str[i][j] = ch;
        j++;
        }
    }

}

}
```